# How to secure APIM protected Azure Functions so that they will only respond to a request from an Azure Web App in same resource group?

Tags: azure, security, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I have a webapp hosted on Azure (MVC/C#/ .Net Core 3.1).

Two new Azure functions, triggered by HTTP and protected by APIM, will be added to the same parent resource group for the webapp to GET data from.

How can I make it such that the Azure functions only respond to GET requests issued by the app? Is there a way of implementing "if originating server is neither Azure box 123-South nor 123-West, return HTTP 403" - or something that might scale better if more functions are added?

Alternatively, is there a way of inspecting HTTP headers in the Azure functions with code?

Our previous Web API, the functions' predecessor, was hosted "on prem". It inspected the headers of the HTTP request looking for a specific base-64 encoded header. If found, the header's value was decoded and checked for correctness. Is it still a valid approach for Azure?

Note: our web app **does not** require users to login via Microsoft or any other identity provider. Our users are the general public and not part of our domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Azure Functions are already secured from direct calls except from APIM by using [IP Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azurecli) or other means, but just wanted to put this out for others coming across this.

There are a few options for you to consider based on your scenario

**1. Use [Client Certificate Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients)**
This would require your Web App to set the client certificate in its requests to APIM.

**2. Use [Azure AD Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)**
Since your clients don't have a token to pass, this could be acceptable in your case. Here your Web App would get a token, using [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json&tabs=portal%2Chttp) or Client Credentials, and pass that along in its requests to APIM.

**3. Set a Custom Header**
This might be the least secure but simplest to implement. You would just add a header in your requests from your Web App and APIM would validate that value using [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/set-edit-policies?tabs=form).

Note that if this is a static value, and your customers somehow get a hold of it, they could then make the calls to APIM directly. Making it dynamic would increase complexity of this option, at which point it might be better to go with #1 or #2.